# Get Access Token from Facebook PHP SDK is not working properly

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to retrieve an Access Token from Facebook using PHP SDK 3.2.2, being the code below what I placed in the redirect url after a sucessfull user login in Facebook. My problem is that **$this->facebook->getAccessToken()** is not giving back the user access token after the user gives access to the APP, just a string with the form: 'AppId|AppSecret', and I have to include code to manually get the User Access Token. This work, but I don't know WHY when I use getAccessToken is not giving back the right Token. I would also like to know how if there is any better way to retrieve User Access Token than with $code, because I don't feel this is a good way of doing it.

NOTE: I use $this->facebook because I load it as a Codeigniter library.

```
  $access_token  = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //echo '<br/>Access Token: ' . $access_token;
  // Generare Token if not created:
  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  if ( isset($code) ) {
     //echo '<br/>Code Enviado: ' . $code;
     //exit();
     $appId     = $this->facebook->getAppId();
     $appSecret = $this->facebook->getAppSecret();

     $redirectTo = base_url('asociar/acc_facebook/step2/');

     $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
        . $appId . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirectTo)
        . "&client_secret=" . $appSecret
        . "&code=" . $code . "&display=popup";
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $params['access_token'];

     //echo '<br/>Repitiendo el Token';

     $this->facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
     //echo '<br/>Second Access Token Fijado: ' . $access_token;
  }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## UPDATE:

This issue is due to I used CI with PHP SDK (check my own answer for that), but the answer is valid to anyone that have this issue with Facebook PHP SDK (Check @Imbru answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is little late, but may be it will help for other users.

I have got the same issue today.

My access_token was not correctly store in $_SESSION. Apparently, client side send juste one time the access_token. You have to store it in memory (SESSION) and reused it.

In normal time, Facebook PHP SDK do it...

EDIT : See @Chococroc response for more explanations

Comment: Hi! I've marked your answer as accepted because although I've not checked it, I'm pretty sure you're right. Codeigniter DON'T USE PHP NATIVE SESSIONS, it sends all the data in the cookie, so, when Facebook SDK tries to save in SESSION the value of the token, it can't.

Answer (score 2):

@Imbru pointed me in the solution, if any credit, give it to him.

Take this into account: when using Codeigniter, it saves all the session data in the cookie and send it to the browser, not storing it in the server. Yes, they do it, and it leads to many other problems (as losing of session when you store a lot of data, and the browser only sends you back part of them, but that is another history).

With CI, the solution is overwrite the session core class, with another session class which manages the session with PHP $_SESSION, as for example, https://bitbucket.org/xperez/core-session-storage-for-codeigniter (I use it in my projects, and work like a charm). In that way, when using PHP-sdk you'll save the values in the session, and when Facebook class will try to retrieve them back, it'll be able of doing it.

And of course, if you're having issues with the Facebook PHP SDK, check if $_SESSION is storing the values you want, as the problem is you don't have the value in the server when you want to retrieve it, leading you to an error of not authentication.